# Get FileInputStream from uri to upload image

Tags: android, uri, ftp-client, registerforactivityresult

> I am successfull in getting image from Gallery or Camera without **WRITE_EXTERNAL_PERMISION** AND **READ_EXTERNAL_PERMISION**

Now I want to upload that image to FTP Server

**ImageSetter.kt**

```
class ImageSetter(
    private val activity: FragmentActivity,
    private val imageView: ImageView,
    val uriCallback:(uri:Uri?) -> Unit,
) : DefaultLifecycleObserver {

    private lateinit var getContent: ActivityResultLauncher<String>
    private lateinit var dispatchTakePicture: ActivityResultLauncher<Uri>

    private val registry = activity.activityResultRegistry
    private var uri: Uri? = null

    override fun onCreate(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        getContent =
            registry.register(
                "select-key",
                owner,
                ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()
            ){
                it?.let{
                    uriCallback.invoke(it)
                    this.uri = it
                    imageView.setImageURI(uri)
                }
            }

        dispatchTakePicture =
            registry.register(
                "take-keys",
                owner,
                ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()
            ){
                if (it) {
                    Log.d("takePicture", "Success")
                    imageView.setImageURI(uri)
                } else {
                    Log.d("takePicture", "Failed")
                }
            }
    }

    fun selectImage(){
        val items = arrayOf("Select an image", "Take Photo")

        AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
            .setItems(items) { dialog, which ->
                Log.d("dialog", dialog.toString())
                Log.d("which", which.toString())
                when(which){
                    0 -> getContent.launch("image/*")
                    1 -> takePicture()
                }
            }
            .show()
    }

    private fun takePicture(){
        val filename = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".jpg"
        val path = activity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        val file = File(path, filename)

        uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity,
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
        uriCallback(uri)
        dispatchTakePicture.launch(uri)
        Log.d("Uri", uri.toString())
    }
}
```

In order to upload **image file to server** I need **InputStream** but I am not able to get the **original imageFile** to publish it to server.

> and do I require any permission to do it.?

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var observer: ImageSetter
    private lateinit var photoIv:ImageView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        photoIv = findViewById(R.id.photoIv)
        observer = ImageSetter(this, photoIv){ photoUri->
        
        var openInputStream = contentResolver?.openInputStream(photoUri!!)
        var format = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
           var file = File(filesDir, "$format.jpg")
           var fileoutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
           openInputStream?.copyTo(fileoutputStream)
           openInputStream?.close()
           fileoutputStream.close()
           fileAbsolutPath = file.absolutePath
  
        }
        lifecycle.addObserver(observer)
        observer.selectImage()
    }
}
```

**Edit**

I have a working class to upload fileInputStream to FTP Server which has a method

```
public static boolean uploadImageFileOnFtpServer(FileInputStream inputStream, String clientFileName){
...
}
```

Now I only want to figure out how to get **fileInputStream from Ur**i.

Comment: I think that an InputStream will do to. Please confirm.

Comment: Further: if you take an image with the camera you use a fileprovider for the path to a file. So in this case you have a path and can use FileInputStream.

Comment: I have uri , How can I convert my uri to fileInputStrem. See Edit please @blackapps

Comment: You are not reacting to what i said. `val file = File(path, filename)` There you have a File instance so you can use it for a new FileInputStream. Further you can pass an InputStream to to your upload function too if you only have an uri.

Comment: `have a working class to upload fileInputStream to FTP Server which has a method` Change it to take an InputStream. Or add an overloaded member for an InputStream. But as you have it now you can pass an InputStream too. I already said that.

Comment: @blackapps I have updated MainActivity and get inputStream uisng var openInputStream = contentResolver?.openInputStream(photoUri!!)
But on uploading 0 kb file uploaded..

Comment: Well i have no idea why you make a copy in onCreate. Further we dont know how you call uploadImageFileOnFtpServer and we also dont know what you do there. So what is it that you ask? Adaot your code so you call the upload function in onActivityResult.

Comment: @blackapps Is it possible to upload image to ftp server get from content uri without read  and write permission ? And secondly am i getting inputStream correctly?

Comment: No permissions needed. Yes getting an input stream using the content resolver is ok.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass URI to get file and make this file inputstream and upload on server.

```
  var file=getFileFromUri(uri!!)
  val inputStream: InputStream = FileInputStream(file)
```

and get file from below method.

```
 fun getFileFromUri(uri: Uri): File? {
        if (uri.path == null) {
            return null
        }
        var realPath = String()
        val databaseUri: Uri
        val selection: String?
        val selectionArgs: Array<String>?
        if (uri.path!!.contains("/document/image:")) {
            databaseUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            selection = "_id=?"
            selectionArgs = arrayOf(DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri).split(":")[1])
        } else {
            databaseUri = uri
            selection = null
            selectionArgs = null
        }
        try {
            val column = "_data"
            val projection = arrayOf(column)
            val cursor = contentResolver.query(
                databaseUri,
                projection,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null
            )
            cursor?.let {
                if (it.moveToFirst()) {
                    val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column)
                    realPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex)
                }
                cursor.close()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.i("GetFileUri Exception:", e.message ?: "")
        }
        val path = if (realPath.isNotEmpty()) realPath else {
            when {
                uri.path!!.contains("/document/raw:") -> uri.path!!.replace(
                    "/document/raw:",
                    ""
                )
                uri.path!!.contains("/document/primary:") -> uri.path!!.replace(
                    "/document/primary:",
                    "/storage/emulated/0/"
                )
                else -> return null
            }
        }
        return File(path)
    }
```